# How can I turn off the page numbering for page 1 / title page only in Libre Office?

Tags: documents, libreoffice-writer, text-formatting, word-processing

The title pretty much asks the question. I don't know how it happened that *all* of my pages have a "First Page" footer, but so 'tis. So: How can I get rid of the page number on page 1 / title page (only).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer in libre office's official site. Check [here](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/13741/how-do-i-begin-page-numbers-on-page-2-in-writer/)

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't work. If you already have a footnote with page numbers, it does nothing (doesn't remove the page number from p. 1 / title page).